# increment half of a log scale step

Tags: python

can't seem to figure this out.

i have a value, for simplicity let it be:

```
a = 1e-4
```

i want to generate numbers that are smaller and larger than a, by half a step in log scale, meaning:

```
b1 = 5e-4
c1 = 5e-5
```

this works by multiplying by 5 or dividing by 2, but the next step requires the opposite - to enlarge further one should multiply by 2 and to reduce, divide by 5, like so:

```
b2 = 1e-3
c2 = 1e-5
```

is there a way i can formulate this task such that for any value of **a** i would be able to get the values of **b** and **c**?

i'm not sure what i mean actually when i say half log steps, but maybe there is a way to formulate this.

Comment: Question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed). Please keep in mind that tags have only to do with the *content* of the question, and not its context.

Comment: what purpose does a tag serve if not to notify members that their knowledge is relevant for a query? 
i'm sure this is the type of question that machine learning experts have tackled before, and so would be able to taylor the right answer. saying it has nothing to do with machine learning is a bit of a strech.

Comment: What do you mean by "to get the values of b and c" is this b1 and c1 or b2 and c2 or a sequence of b = b1, b2, ... and c = c1, c2, ... or something else?

Comment: "i'm not sure what i mean actually when i say half log steps, but maybe there is a way to formulate this." Then you have a math question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.accumulate` with custom func to generate the sequence.

The input sequence is alternating sequence (5, 2, 5, 2, ...).

```py
import itertools


def main():
    a = 1e-4

    count = 3

    print(list(itertools.accumulate([5, 2] * count, lambda s, t: s * t, initial=a)))
    print(list(itertools.accumulate([1 / 2, 1 / 5] * count, lambda s, t: s * t, initial=a)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

output:

```
[0.0001, 0.0005, 0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1]
[0.0001, 5e-05, 1e-05, 5e-06, 1.0000000000000002e-06, 5.000000000000001e-07, 1.0000000000000002e-07]
```

Answer (score 0):

The distance between consecutive b's (or c's) is not equal, not even after taking the log. So it is normal that your own defined sequence needs a "special" way of creating it. Something like this seems the easiest solution to me:

```
b = [a*5]
c = [a/2]
for i in range(0, n, 2):  # n = number of elements you want in b and c.
     b.append(b[i]*2)
     b.append(b[i+1]*5)
     c.append(c[i]/5)
     c.append(c[i+1]/2)
```